# How to filter date between 2 field in array node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my array object

```
let getPeriod = [
  {
    deleted: false,
    _id: 6051ae1437daba27db4a9bf4,
    period: 'P1',
    dateStart: '2020-12-28',
    dateEnd: '2021-01-24',
    createdAt: 2021-03-17T07:21:56.497Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-17T07:25:07.382Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    deleted: false,
    _id: 6052d717e141450e696eea97,
    period: 'P3',
    dateStart: '2020-02-22',
    dateEnd: '2021-03-21',
    createdAt: 2021-03-18T04:29:11.885Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-18T04:29:11.885Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    deleted: false,
    _id: 605aade7c7a70069e429d3d2,
    period: 'P4',
    dateStart: '2020-03-22',
    dateEnd: '2021-04-18',
    createdAt: 2021-03-24T03:11:35.962Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-24T03:11:35.962Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I want to  use moment to get today date and use in filter with period is in this time

```
const today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

//2021-03-29
```

this is what I try to do

```
getPeriod = getPeriod.filter(
    (item) => item.dateStart >= today && item.dateEnd <= today
  );
```

but it's return in [] not use why because It suppose to return `preiod: P4 object`

**UPDATE**

Now I use this

```
 getPeriod = getPeriod.filter((item) => {
    console.log(moment(item.dateStart), moment(item.dateEnd), today);
    moment(item.dateStart).isSameOrAfter(today) &&
      moment(item.dateEnd).isSameOrBefore(today);
  });
```

and in console log I got this

```
Moment<2020-12-28T00:00:00+07:00> Moment<2021-01-24T00:00:00+07:00> Moment<2021-03-29T12:45:21+07:00>
Moment<2020-02-22T00:00:00+07:00> Moment<2021-03-21T00:00:00+07:00> Moment<2021-03-29T12:45:21+07:00>
Moment<2020-03-22T00:00:00+07:00> Moment<2021-04-18T00:00:00+07:00> Moment<2021-03-29T12:45:21+07:00>
```

still not sure why it still return null data

**UPDATE2**

I add return in still get null

```
getPeriod = getPeriod.filter((item) => {
    if (
      moment(item.dateStart).isSameOrAfter(today) &&
      moment(item.dateEnd).isSameOrBefore(today)
    ) {
      return item;
    }
  });
```

Comment: add `return` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment until to create filter condition:

```
const today = moment(); // Keep today is a moment object
getPeriod = getPeriod.filter(
    (item) => moment(item.dateEnd).isSameOrAfter(today) && moment(item.dateStart).isSameOrBefore(today);
);
```

Ref: [document](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/)

Update:
Because you want to it returns `period: 'P4'`, then I updated the condition.

Comment: I try these but not sure why it still return null value

I try to log ( dateStart,dateEnd ) I also have this 2020-03-22, 2021-04-18

Comment: I just updated my question I my full console log in it

Comment: @Akw `filter` function always returns an array.

Comment: Oh I see would you please update your answer. I also try to add it but still null. I updated2 in my question

Comment: @Akw this is not null, this an empty array. I updated my answer, changed the condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use momentjs to compare dates, then your dates should be created using momentjs.

```
getPeriod = getPeriod.filter(
    (item) => (moment(item.dateStart) <= today && moment(item.dateEnd) >= today)
);
```

Comment: I also try this but It's return null same

Comment: I try is ok, console.log(moment.now() > moment("2020-12-28")); // true。